# MVC Last record repeated instead of deleted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC application that will list names. The names are in an entity framework database. A timer is beside the first name in the list and when the timer ends, the name is deleted from the list and the database (this continues until no names are left). The application starts by displaying 5 names from the database. My issue is that when the last record is reached, instead of deleting the record, it repeats it over and over. Any ideas of what I have wrong?

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RangeTimer.Models.UserName>


<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">

<table class="table" id="NameList">
    <tr>

        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>

        <th>
            Time Remaining
        </th>

    </tr>


</table>
<div id="message"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var usersList = [];

    function init() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "UserNames")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {

                var row = null,
                    first = true,
                    timer = null;

                // populate local users list:
                usersList = data;

                // populate HTML for table:
                $.each(usersList, function (index, item) {
                    row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.Id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');

                    // add a timer to the first row:
                    if (first) {
                        $(row).append(getTimer());
                        first = false;
                    }

                    $('#NameList').append(row);
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    init();

    function restartTimer() {

        var deletedElement = null,
            nextId = null,
            newRow = null,
            row = null,
            that = this;

        // remove the deleted item from local array:
        deletedElement = usersList.shift();

        // delete record from db on server:
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "UserNames")',
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ id: deletedElement.Id }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {

                // remove this timer:
                $(that).remove();

                // add new record to local array:
                usersList.push(data);


                // add html for row:

                newRow = $('<tr id="row-' + data.Id + '"><td>' + data.FullName + '</td></tr>');

                console.log(newRow);
                $('#NameList').append(newRow);

                //remove the html for deleted user:
                $('#row-' + deletedElement.Id).remove();

                if (usersList.length > 0) {

                    // get the next item id:
                    nextId = usersList[0].Id;

                    // add a timer to the new item:
                    row = $('#row-' + nextId);
                    row.append(getTimer());
                    }
               // else {
                //    $("#message").add("No records to display.")
                //}
            }

        });
    }



    function getTimer() {
        var timer = $('<td></td>');
        $(timer).countdown({
            layout: '{mnn} : {snn}', timeSeparator: ':', until: 35, onTick: TimerColorChange, onExpiry: restartTimer
        });
        return timer;
    }

    function TimerColorChange(periods) {

        var seconds = $.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods);
        if (seconds <= 3) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "black");
        }

    }
});

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class UserNamesController : Controller
{
    private UserNameDBContext db = new UserNameDBContext();

    // GET: UserNames
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.UserNames.Take(0).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View(db.UserNames.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList());
    }

    // GET: UserNames/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: UserNames/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName")] UserName userName)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserNames.Add(userName);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // return RedirectToAction("Create");
            return View();
        }

        return View(userName);
    }

    // GET: AddUserName 
    public ActionResult AddUserName()
    {       
        return View();
    }

    //Post method to add details   
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUserName(UserName obj)
    {
        AddDetails(obj);
        TempData["Message"] = obj.FullName + " has been added to the list successfully.";
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }

   private void AddDetails(UserName obj)
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GetAddName  @FullName", new SqlParameter("@FullName", obj.FullName));
    }
    // GET: UserNames/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(id);

        if (userName == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(userName);
    }

    // POST: UserNames/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName")] UserName userName)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(userName).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(userName);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetNames()
    {
        return Json(db.UserNames.OrderBy(c=>c.Id).Take(5).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        // TODO: Add delete logic here

        UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(Id);

        db.UserNames.Remove(userName);

        db.SaveChanges();

        //Find the new user
        var query = db.UserNames.OrderBy(c => c.Id).Take(5).ToList();

         UserName newUserName = query[query.Count - 1];

        return Json(newUserName);
    }

    // GET: UserNames/Delete/5
    public ActionResult DeleteFromAdmin(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(id);

        if (userName == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(userName);
    }


    //// POST: UserNames/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteFromAdmin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int Id, string name)
    {
        UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(Id);

        db.UserNames.Remove(userName);

        db.SaveChanges();

        //return Json(newUserName);

       return RedirectToAction("Admin");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose()
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are no records left in the database? I assume following line will actually throw you an exception if this is true: `UserName newUserName = query[query.Count - 1];` At least, you should check the index value before accessing the list. Or better return single value from database

Comment: Yes, the database had records. It does eventually error out on that line. I need it to run through the records (even the last one) and remove it. It will add the last record to the end of the list over and over.

Comment: Why not to fix that error first and then try again?